# Why saveAs() in JavaScript does not work for me?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to save a graph to a JSON file. Before doing that, I wrote a very simple HTML/JavaScript to test it out (just use a simple string for the JSON).

Based on the suggestion in a Stack Overflow posting, I use saveAs() method. But it looks like saveAs() does not work and no file is created. I am using Internet Explorer and Window 10.

In order to debug it, I inserted 3 window.alert() calls. The first 2 window.alert() calls pop up correctly, however, the 3rd window.alert() call does not show up at all. So I am afraid that the code is aborted at the saveAs() call.

The following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Save</title>
<script>

function save() 
{ 
window.alert("I am here 1");
var jsonBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify("kiki")], { type: 'application/javascript;charset=utf-8' });
window.alert("I am here 2");
saveAs(jsonBlob, "testout.json");
window.alert("I am here 3");
} 

</script> 
</head>
<body> 
<form name="myform"> 
<input type="button" onClick="save();" value="Save">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering why saveAs() does not work for me? Am I missing something here? Do I need to add something to my computer in order to use saveAs() method?

Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: Are you showing all of your code? You need to define `saveAs`.

Comment: *"Based on the suggestion in a Stack Overflow posting"* Can you link to the post? `saveAs` is not a built-in function.

Comment: Include [FileSaver](https://github.com/yrezgui/FileSaver.js) script. `saveAs` is not a default API, it's a library's command. But note that in IE, you've got [`msSaveBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772331(v=vs.85).aspx) API, which doesn't need a lib (only available in IE).

Comment: Your browser's console is where you can check for errors in such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! Your advice is very helpful! By including FileSaver.js, it works now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a little bit error in saveAs.
Code is given below:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Save</title>
    <script>

    function save() 
    { 
    window.alert("I am here 1");
    var jsonBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify("kiki")], { type: 'application/javascript;charset=utf-8' });
    window.alert("I am here 2");
   var link=window.URL.createObjectURL(jsonBlob);
    window.location=link;
    window.alert("I am here 3");
    } 

    </script> 
    </head>
    <body> 
    <form name="myform"> 
    <input type="button" onClick="save();" value="Save">
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Also you can see this: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! By including FileSaver.js, it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: @qcx if it is solved your problem,then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Convert into excel sheet using JavaScript

```
var excelBlob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }, "excel.xlsx");     
var link=window.URL.createObjectURL(excelBlob);
window.location=link;
```